# unable to boot into ubuntu or shell

Tags: command-line, startup, grub2

Okay so let's start off with why im an idiot: I used

```
sudo mv /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 lib64
```

I realize how stupid this is but it's what I did and now I just want to fix it.

I attempted to move it back but as most of you probably already know the mv function is dependent on /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

After googling the problem and having nothing work I tried to restart it. I am now unable to start my computer, I cannot boot into shell, when I attempt to boot into a usb partition the exact same thing happens (yes I am making sure it is booting to the usb not the hard drive). I can get to grub and BIOS but that is about it.

Here is the error I am getting on startup:

```
Begin:running /scripts/init-bottom... done.
[ 4.795453] sdb: sdb1
[ 4.798186] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 4.798232] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4.798267] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
[ 4.937526] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[ 4.937526]
```

once it gets to this point the cursor continues to blink but no input is accepted even ctrl+alt+delete to restart. the capslock and numlock buttons start flashing on my keybord I doubt that's important but just in case.

My first choice would be to restore the current build however I've more or less given up hope on that and would settle wiping my computer and starting over.

any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am offering an answer here which I hope will get migrated with the question.

The easiest way to fix this kind of problem is to boot from a LiveUSB and just move the file back, and then reboot your machine again.

Comment: I made a few mistakes while doing this. The truth was that I was not actually using a LiveUSB (to get this just follow the instructions on ubuntu.com). Once I did that everything worked much better. Just to add to this answer the path to the normal computer when you're in the usb is root/media/ubuntu/[RANDOM STRING OF NUMBERS]/path/to/error